# BlocBuilder partially update ListView

Tags: flutter, bloc

#### Project

Hi, I'm trying to use a bloc pattern to create a list view that can be filtered by a `TextField`

Here is my **code**

bloc:

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {

  List<Book> displayList = [];

  .... 

  @override
  HomeState get initialState => UnfilteredState();

  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
    HomeEvent event,
  ) async* {

    .... 

    //handle filter by input
    if(event is FilterListByTextEvent) {

      displayList = displayList.where((book){
        return book.title.toLowerCase().contains(event.filterString.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();

      yield FilteredState();
    }

  }

}
```

view

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        final HomeBloc bloc = Provider.of<HomeBloc>(context);
        print(bloc.displayList);
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: bloc.displayList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              background: Container(
                color: selectedColor,
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 120,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 4, 20, 4),
                child: BookCard(
                  book: bloc.displayList[index],
                ),
              ),
              onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### Problem

I've read some other discussion about bloc pattern and List view but the issue I'm facing here is different.

Every time my Filter event is called, bloc correctly generate a new `displayList` but, when `BlocBuilder` rebuild my UI, listview is not correctly updated. 
The new filtered list is rendered but old results do not disappear. It seems like the new list is simply stacked on top of the old one.

In order to understand what was happening I tried printing the list that has to be rendered, inside the BlocBuilder before the build method is called.

The printed result was correct. In the console I see only the new filtered elements while in the UI I see both the new one and the old one, one below the other.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep an intermediate event, eg. a ListInit for which you will display a CircularProgressIndicator. BlocBuilder will be stuck on previous state unless you update it over again.

So in your bloc, first yield the ListInit state and then perform filtering operations, and then yield your FilteredState.

Answer (score 1):

Make new state for loading and yield before displayList.

```
if(event is FilterListByTextEvent) {
    yield LoadFilterList();
    displayList = displayList.where((book)
    {
        return 
        book.title.toLowerCase().contains(event.filterString.toLowerCase());
    }).toList();

    yield FilteredState();
}
```